# VMWare workstation Centos VM unable to obtain LAN IPIV IP address using bridged network

Tags: centos, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation Pro 12.5.7 build-5813279.

I created Centox 7.x VM with network setting to use NAT vs Bridged Connection.

After Centos is installed the VM and the ifconfig shows the IP address of inet 192.168.253 on ens33.
It also shows inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx (x being hexa values).

However, I want to use a local network IP(DHCP) address on this VM so I change the network setting to
Bridged Connection and I give it a reboot. Then I get no IP IV address and it only shows the
inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx (x being hexa values).

When I use the Bridged connection for Oracle Virual Box VM I do not have this issue and I'm able to get the
local Ip address.

How can I get the Ip IV ip address from my local network's DHCP using VMWare workstation VM?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See "What topics can I ask about here" in the [help/on-topic]. Perhaps [su] or [unix.se] would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from root:

`dhclient –v`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

- Go to File -> Edit -> Virtual Network Editor
- Use the Change Settings" button
- Highlight the first selection VMnet0
- Under VMnet Information choose the "Automatic Setting" button
  You will get a list of all of the adapters on your system.
- Uncheck ones that might be causing the issue.
- Click "Apply" then "OK"

Should help.
:)